# how to let KONG follow the 301 redirect?

Tags: redirect, kong

I found an issue in a new KONG installation (v0.11.2).

When an upstream api return HTTP 301, the KONG will pass this to consumer side instead of following the redirect in the internal process. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCaXj.png)

Please advise how to let KONG follow the 301 redirect (as an expected reverse proxy behavior)?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out @fangchih ?

Comment: Not yet, fortunately, the HTTP 301 is not a normal behavior in API response, what I can do now is prevent this happened from API end in my current project. I'll try to trace the source to find out the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround instead of having to deploy a separate web server, if you register DNS through GoDaddy, you can enable their "Domain Forward & Mask" features. What I was trying to enable is a redirect from root domain to `www.domain` and enforce https.

- https://www.godaddy.com/help/manually-forward-or-mask-your-domain-or-subdomain-422

Since DNS was pointed from GoDaddy nameservers, they update the A record pointing to their own configurable proxy, and I was able to enter the redirect URL. Perhaps other domain registrars offer this feature, and it can avoid "hacky" configuration of Kong.

### Attempts with Kong

- I enabled the request transform plugin for an API and tried overriding the header host and forwarded values to no avail
- I tried variations on the downstream url as well

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm wondering if it's possible to have the 301 stay internal, deploy KONG or API Service on a different machine is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect only for specific upstream APIs, you can use the `pre-function` plugin.

```
name: my-redirect
kind: KongPlugin
namespace: my-namespace
global: "false"
plugin: pre-function
config:
  access:
    - |
      if ngx.var.uri == "/product/1" then
        local forwarded_host = "new-domain.com"
        ngx.header["Location"] = "https://" .. forwarded_host .. ngx.var.request_uri
        return kong.response.exit(301)
      end
```

This will redirect traffic from let's say `old-domain.com/product/1` to `new-domain.com/product/1`